# Access private instance variable of parent class

Tags: objective-c

I can't figure out why class B can access class A private instance variable.
Here is my code

A.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface A : NSObject 
{

@private
    int x;
}

@property int x;

-(void)printX;
@end
```

A.m

```
#import "A.h"

@implementation A
@synthesize x;

-(void)printX
{
    NSLog(@"%i", x);
}

@end
```

B.h

```
 #import "A.h"

    @interface B : A 
    {

    }

    @end
```

main.m

```
    B *tr = [[B alloc] init];
    tr.x = 10; 
    [tr printX];
```

Here I can access instance variable of A class x despite it is declarated as private ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accessing the private variable there, at least not directly: you are accessing a public property, which has legitimate access to the private ivar.

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
B *tr = [[B alloc] init];
[tr setX:10]; 
[tr printX];
```

The `@synthesize` statement created the getter and the setter methods for you. If you want only a getter to be available, mark your property `readonly`, and do all writings through an ivar in the `A` class.

Answer (score -1):

In your implementation file do this on the top..

```
@interface A : NSObject 
{

@private
    int x;
}
@property int x;
@end
```

this way x will be private since it is in the implementation file. not the interface section...all classes import the interface section of A ..so it's variable are accessible to its subclasses.